# matplotlib.widget.Slider displays but isn't active when plt.show() is called outside function that created the slider. Am I missing something?

Tags: graphics

```
###################
# create_slider() #
###################
def create_slider(self, t0, t1):
    
    # adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
    
    slider = Slider(
        #                   left  botm   w     h
        ax      = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03]),
        label   = '"t"',
        valmin  = t0,
        valmax  = t1,
        valinit = t0,
        valstep = (t1-t0)/200.0,
        color   = 'lime'
    )
    
    slider.on_changed(self.update)
    
    plt.show()
    
##############
# __init__() #
##############
def __init__(self, p0, p1, p2, p3, t0, t1):
    
    self.create_curve(p0, p1, p2, p3, t0, t1)
    self.create_unit_lines(t0)
    self.create_slider(t0, t1)
    #
    # Slider INACTIVE IF CALLED HERE VS. IN create_slider
    #
    # plt.show()
```

Comment: `Am I missing something?` Missing a possible trigger for disapproval&down-votes: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on/129632#129632)

Answer (score 0):

Found answer under button issue. Need to maintain class reference to the slider.  Replace "slider" with "self.slider" works.